# Suddenly got weird colors in mkv movies

Tags: vlc, totem, mkv

Suddenly I got weird colors in mkv movies in both VLC and Totem on Ubuntu 11.10. The sound is ok.

[image: weird colors in mkv]

Anybody know what is the problem and how to fix it.